# Separate data having comma in between using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

In a column, I have address and area of plot mentioned and all the data is separated by comma:

```
Fee quote, 1/1, survey office number 54, 5,999,999 m2
```

5,999,999 m2 is the value I am interested in as it gives the area of the plot.

- I want to convert this value into hectares by dividing it by 10,000.
- I want to run a query to retrieve all values more than 4 hectares and save them in a new table.

P.S. We can separate all values after fourth comma to get area, then delete m2, divide it by 10,000 and then run my query. This is what I feel.

Any advice on the sytax which needs to be used ?

Comment: Querying your data would be *a lot* easier if it wasn't all in one column.  Multiple columns and multiple data types exist for a reason.

Comment: This isn't a database, this is a spreadsheet gagged, blindfolded, and stuffed in the trunk of a database at gunpoint. Express your data as columns and tables, as one does in [a relational database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: To aid in the points above, what we're all referring to is called normalization. You should really have all different types of data in their own field, or column, or row or table; whatever makes sense in the end.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: Garbage in. Garbage out, I'm afraid.

Comment: Hey guys. It is a complete table with multiple rows such as country, plot no, etc etc. however I am only concerned with this one column as the first query of my project is : retrieve info of plots more than 3 hectares

Comment: See substring_index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question was to use substring_index function.

eg: update table set

```
area=substring_index(column_name,"",-1)
```